# Stop Clang from optimizing out variables at -O0?

Tags: debugging, optimization, clang++

We are experiencing a crash on an edge test case under Clang. The edge case manually enables all X86 cpu features because Clang does not always enable them with `-march=native`. The case also includes the address sanitizer:

```
$ CXX=clang++ make CXXFLAGS="-DDEBUG -g3 -O0 -std=c++03 -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -msse4.2
-maes -mpclmul -mrdrnd -mrdseed -mavx -mavx2 -mbmi -mbmi2 -madx -march=native -fPIC -pipe
-fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer"
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Later, when we run the program under GDB, variables and values are missing:

```
$ gdb cryptest.exe
...
(gdb) r v
...
Testing RDRAND generator...

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000001db20b4 in CryptoPP::GCC_RRA_GenerateBlock (output=<optimized out>, 
    size=<optimized out>, safety=<optimized out>) at rdrand.cpp:235
235         __asm__ volatile(
```

How do we stop Clang from optimizing out variables at `-O0`?

---

We have rebuilt the library and test program several times to ensure something with optimizations was not accidentally used.

```
$ clang --version
Ubuntu clang version 3.6.0-2ubuntu1~trusty1 (tags/RELEASE_360/final) (based on LLVM 3.6.0)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Person93 - Sorry, no.